# Efficiently add a value to a new column in a large DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have two dataframes, `adv_text` with about 9,000 rows and `events` with over 900,000 rows. `events` is essentially an expanded version of `adv_text` with about 100 rows per row in `adv_text`. I want to add three columns from `adv_text` to `events`.

The following code is a partial addition of one column.

```
events_x = events.head(30000).copy()

def add_date(game_id):
    date = adv_text[adv_text['id_odsp'] == game_id]['date']
    return(date.iloc[0])

events_x['date'] = events_x['id_odsp'].apply(add_date)
```

This test code takes almost 25 seconds for 30,000 rows. At this speed, adding all three columns over the full dataframe will take nearly 40 minutes. Is this typical? Is there a faster way to accomplish this task?

Comment: Can you show what your dataframes look like? It seems that you're trying to merge you dataframes based on `game_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, one way is to use [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
events_x['date'] = events_x.merge(adv_text[['id_odsp', 'date']], on='id_odsp')['date']
```

More information: [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53645882/15239951)

Comment: Thanks. I thought that `merge` might be a good solution, but I didn't know how to fill in the values for all of the rows in `events`.